# Find and Append String Regex Php

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm very new to php, but this problem may require regex manipulation. Basically all "" in my website points to localhost (i.e. img src="http://localhost/folder/img.png" ).
When viewed under source, the "localhost" doesn't show up, but if clicked to get image address, it'll show "localhost". What i need is then to add the full path to that img src (i.e. img src="http://mywebsite.com/folder/img.png" ).

How do i go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute URLs in your project to reduce conflicts and messy overheads. To use absolute URLs, just define a global constant `BASE_URL` in your common file like:

```
define("BASE_URL", "http://localhost/project_folder", true);
```

Now use it everywhere, like:

```
<img src="<?php echo BASE_URL.'/img/image.png' ?>" />
```

In source code, generated html will look like: `<img src="http://localhost/project_folder/img/image.png" />`

Similary you can use this like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/js/my_script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i forgot to mention that i don't have access to the site itself as i'm not allowed to, and i'm only creating a reader for it on mobile site using rss. Is it possible?

Comment: Whoops! Anyways, in PHP--you can use other site's RSS as `$rss = simplexml_load_file("http://domain.com/rss.xml")` and then getting nodes by `$photos = $rss->channel->item`, in this way.